# How to capture a number of divs/ tables at once

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am using Scrapy with the following url:

http://www.marzetti.com/products/marzetti/detail.php?bc=35&cid=2&pid=1101&i=pl

I need to capture in the same scrapy item, the following:

```
/html/body/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]  /div[4]
/html/body/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div[4]`
```

So here's my code snippet:

```
hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('/html/body/div/div[2]/table/tr[3]/td[4]/table/tr')
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        ..............
        item['description'] = site.select('td/div[2]/table/tr[2]/td[2]/div[4] or div[5]//text()').extract()
```

However, this returns a Boolean answer such as 'description = True', whereas what I need is the actual text within the two divs.

Any suggestions welcome. Thanks.
-TM

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a short and easy one-liner XPath expression. :)

Comment: You say you need to extract two different, specific xpath, yet the ones you mention seem to be the same. Also, those xpaths contain tbody, yet your example code does not.

Answer (score 0):

**Use the standard XPath union operator '|'** :

```
  (td/div[2]/table/tr[2]/td[2]/div[4]
| 
   div[5])
          //text()
```

Comment: I am not familiar with Scrapy, but my guess is that you want to get the string value of the selected node-set. In XPath 1.0 the string value of a node-set is the string value of the first node (in document order) of this node-set. To summarize, the XPath expression in my answer correctly selects all wanted text nodes. You may verify this by making this expression the argument of the `count()` function and thus getting the number of nodes that are selected. If you want to output all selected text nodes, this cannot be done with a single XPath 1.0 expression and you *must* use the host language.

Comment: Continued: For example, if the language hosting XPath is XSLT 1.0, you can output at once all the selected text nodes using a single `<xsl:copy-of select="theExpression"/>`

Comment: Continued: I got the HTML pointed to by the link in your question, adjusted it slightly to make it well-formed XML document and using XSLT as the host, applied the XPath expression from my anser. Passing this XPath expression as the argument of the `count()` function, I see that 3 nodes are selected.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre, I appreciate your effort. This is however not solving the problem for me.

Comment: @user818190: It isn't constructive to say that something "didn't work". What isn't working, what was the input, what was the xslt code, what output was produced, what was the wanted output, how the actual output differed from the wanted output, what error messages were produced? You are literally wasting your time and that of many others if you don't provide this data and keep saying: "This is however not solving the problem for me"